# Prevent escaping of Logbook JSON when using logstash-logback-encoder

Tags: java, logstash-logback-encoder, logbook

My project uses Zalando Logbook to log requests and responses in JSON format. I'm introducing JSON logging to the team using logstash-logback-encoder in preparation for ELK log processing.

Is there a way to configure the logstash encoder to not escape the JSON string generated by Logbook?

So far I've come up with this so that Logbook's content appears un-escaped and lives in structure under http. Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same thing? Perhaps there is a Logbook sub-project I'm not aware of that supports structured logging?

```xml
<appender name="logbook_console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <timestamp/>
            <version/>
            <loggerName/>
            <threadName/>
            <logLevel/>
            <stackTrace/>
            <tags/>
            <mdc/>
            <arguments/>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                    "http": "#tryJson{%message}"
                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
            <context/>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Here's the desired output.

```json
  {

    "@timestamp": "2024-03-27T13:46:04.918002526-04:00",

    "@version": "1",

    "logger_name": "org.zalando.logbook.Logbook",

    "thread_name": "reactor-http-epoll-8",

    "level": "TRACE",

    "http": {

      "origin": "local",

      "type": "response",

      "correlation": "c671f441706b23c6",

      "duration": 11,

      "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",

      "status": 503,

      "headers": {

        "Cache-Control": [

          "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"

        ],

        "Content-Length": [

          "139"

        ],

        "Content-Type": [

          "application/problem+json"

        ],

        "Expires": [

          "0"

        ],

        "Pragma": [

          "no-cache"

        ],

        "Referrer-Policy": [

          "no-referrer"

        ],

        "X-Content-Type-Options": [

          "nosniff"

        ],

        "X-Frame-Options": [

          "DENY"

        ],

        "X-Request-ID": [

          "d759866e-19a9-4a36-84c8-4552eb22b9bc"

        ],

        "X-XSS-Protection": [

          "0"

        ]

      },

      "body": {

        "type": "about:blank",

        "title": "Service Unavailable",

        "status": 503,

        "detail": "API is unavailable",

        "instance": "/v1/gateways/ABC/config"

      }

    }
  }
```